# Send JSON from MySQL query in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

Currently my NodeJS code sends JSON back in the following format;

```
{"data":
 [
  {"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Josie ","email":"josie@gmail.com"},
  {"audioname":"mytalk40.m4a","name":"Jessie James","email":"jesse@gmail.com"}, 
  {"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Joan Bologney","email":"joan@gmail.com"}
 ]
}
```

But I'd like to get rid of the "data" and send back just;

```
 [
  {"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Josie ","email":"josie@gmail.com"},
  {"audioname":"mytalk40.m4a","name":"Jessie James","email":"jesse@gmail.com"}, 
  {"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Joan Bologney","email":"joan@gmail.com"}
 ]
```

Here's the query;

```
query = mysql.format(query);

connection.query(query,function(err,data){
    if(err) {
        res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
    } else {
        res.json({data});
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why have you wrapped `data` in an Object literal `{}` to begin with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing the inner brackets seemed to work;

res.json(data);

Answer (score 0):

If the object shown above is available though the `data` variable, we can pass only the `data` array by using:

```js
res.json(data.data);
```

Where the second `data` references to the `data` array in the `data` variable.

---

Small example:

```js
const data = {"data": [{"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Josie ","email":"josie@gmail.com"}, {"audioname":"mytalk40.m4a","name":"Jessie James","email":"jesse@gmail.com"}, {"audioname":"mytalk.m4a","name":"Joan Bologney","email":"joan@gmail.com"} ] };

console.log(data.data);
```

Comment: That produced a blank white page. However what did work was simply to remove the brackets: IE res.json(data);